# Como converter ASCII para binário?

Tags: c#, .net, string, operadores, binary

Estou tentando implementar a conversão de um texto para binário, achei um pela internet:

```
static string ASCII_binary(string texto)
        {
            string converted = string.Empty;
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(texto);

            for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                {
                    converted += (byteArray[i] & 0x80) > 0 ? "1" : "0";
                    byteArray[i] <<= 1;
                }
            }

            return converted;
        }
```

Mas não estou conseguindo entender `0x80` para que serve? Tem alguma outra maneira de fazer esta conversão?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dê uma olhada no [código mostrando cada passo no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/A7QaFq) que ajuda entender um pouco melhor. Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/3ANNHf). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conversion/ASCII2BinSimple.cs).

O `0x80` é o hexadecimal do número decimal 128 que em binário é o `10000000`. Quando ele aplica o operador `&` de `and`, cada bit de um número é comparado com outro e o resultado será 1 se ambos forem 1, ou 0 se ambos forem 0 ou se apenas um deles for 1. É assim que este operador funciona. Então no exemplo da letra `t` ele começa com

```
01110100
&
10000000
--------
00000000
```

Deu zero.

No passo seguinte é aplicado o operador `<<` que é o deslocamento, ou seja ele joga todos os bits para a esquerda, então fica assim:

```
11101000
&
10000000
--------
10000000
```

Deu 128, ou seja, maior que zero, então ele sabe que deve usar a *string* `1`.

E vai fazendo isto com todos os outros bits.

Note que usando o número 128 (0x80) estamos sempre comparando apenas o primeiro bit, ou outros sempre darão 0 em qualquer situação já que no número 128 todos os bits serão 0, exceto o primeiro. O operador de `and`, neste caso, só variará de acordo com o primeiro bit do número, os demais serão resultarão em 0.

Esta é a forma de andar passo a passo pelos bits e analisar só o primeiro. Até existem outras formas, mas será menos eficiente.

Veja o [jeito ineficiente no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YkLEze). Pode parecer mais legível para quem não entende operadores de bits. Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/VzHitI). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conversion/ASCII2Bin.cs).

Veja o [teste de performance no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0fMVjX). Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/jGBxwI). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conversion/ASCII2BinPerformance.cs).

Se considerar que outras operações do algoritmo tem um custo bem alto, o simples uso do operador de bit no lugar do operador aritmético provavelmente gera, na operação isolada, mais de uma ordem de magnitude de velocidade.

O teste deve ser feito no seu computador. O .NET Fiddle não é confiável por ter vários processos rodando ao mesmo tempo. Mas dá uma base inicial.

Comment: E como converteria de binário para ASCII?

Comment: @MoribundoChat isso é outra questão, mas algo assim funciona `Convert.ToInt32("1001101", 2)`.

Comment: com boa eficiência ou não seria a maneira mais adequada?

Comment: @MoribundoChat é o mais simples, ñ fiz testes, não sei se é tão eficiente quanto poderia.

Answer (score 3):

Basicamente o que o codigo está fazendo na linha

```
converted += (byteArray[i] & 0x80) > 0 ? "1" : "0";
```

é comparar o bit mais significativo do ByteArray e verificando se é 1 ou 0 fazendo uma and bit a bit com 0x80

Dai ele pega o valor do ByteArray e desloca os bits do caractere uma casa para esquerda, fazendo este processo para todos os 8 bits do caractere.

A representação de 0x80 em hexadecimal é esta : 10000000.