# Por que arquivos não mostram seus bits?

Tags: arquivo, txt, binary, .exe

Por exemplo, eu abro um arquivo `.exe` com o bloco de notas e vejo em vez de 100101 eu vejo um monte caracteres estranhos por que isto? Que caracteres são aqueles?

Um arquivo `.txt` também é binário?

Como posso ver os bits de um arquivo e talvez editá-los? Se editar de forma certa um .exe posso programar em binário? Mesmo que seja difícil.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 5):

> eu abro um arquivo `.exe` com o bloco de notas e vejo em vez de 100101 eu vejo um monte caracteres estranhos por que isso? Que caracteres são aqueles?

Porque o bloco de notas quis mostrar assim. O que você vê é só uma representação gráfica (em amplo sentido) de uma informação. Cada software mostra do jeito que ela achar melhor para a pessoa. E a pessoa que for ver escolhe o software que for mais adequado para que seja apesentado do jeito que ela queira. Abrir um executável em um bloco de notas não costuma ser uma ideia muito boa, ainda que funcione.

O bloco de notas foi feito para mostrar textos, então ele pega o que tem no arquivo e tenta mostrar da melhor forma possível como se fosse um texto segundo a tabela ASCII estendida.

[Respondi sobre isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/451664/101).

> Um arquivo `.txt` também é binário?

Provavelmente não, mas não posso garantir, a extensão do arquivo não garante o que tem dentro dele. Em geral esse é um caso que tem caracteres mais limitados e fazem mais sentido para um humano. Claro que ele é binário no sentido que todo arquivo é formado por bits, mas em outro nível de abstração classificação como binário só os arquivos que possuem mais do que textos legível para humanos.

> Como posso ver os bits de um arquivo e talvez editá-los?

Você não pode ver os bits como está no computador porque é só energia elétrica ou magnética (para citar os tipos mais comuns, é possível ter outras formas). Você vê a energia em algum lugar?

Você pode ver uma representação do que eles são. Tem que pegar um software que mostre os dados de um arquivo bit a bit de uma forma abstrata que você consegue entender.

Exemplos:

- [Visual Studo tem um](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/binary-editor?view=vs-2019).
- [Binary View](https://www.proxoft.com/BinaryViewer.aspx).
- [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/).
- [Free Hex Editor](https://freehexeditorneo.com/).
- [Hexed (online)](https://hexed.it/).

Não estou recomendando qualquer deles, não sei a qualidade ou problema de algum.

> Se editar de forma certa um `.exe` posso programar em binário?

Pode, mas o último que fez isso acabou em um hospício. :P :D

Answer (score 4):

De 8 em 8 bits forma um byte, cada byte em codificação ASCII é mostrado como um caracter (ou em alguma outra codificação; o número de bits que representa o caracter pode variar).

Ou tentando explicar melhor:

O bloco de notas foi feito pra lidar com texto. Texto no computador é exibido pegando-se os bits em grupos de 8 ou mais e exibindo um caracter no lugar, esse caracter é definido em uma tabela, por exemplo a [tabela ASCII](https://web.fe.up.pt/%7Eee96100/projecto/Tabela%20ascii.htm), se foi usada essa codificação.

Arquivos .txt também são guardados como bits.

Para ver os bits você precisa de um editor de hexadecimal (hex editor) e saber lidar com números em base hexadecimal (isto é, base 16). Ou então achar um editor de binário, mas como os grupos de 8 bits são fáceis de enxergar em base 8 (octal) ou 16 os editores de hexadecimal dão bem conta do recado.

A base que a gente aprendeu na escola é base 10, a 16 é parecida só que com o acréscimo das letras A (10), B (11), C (12), D (13), E (14) e F (15). As operações soma, subtração etc. também têm jeito específico de fazer.

Não convém editar um .exe num editor de texto porque ele trunca e corrompe o arquivo original quando este é carregado e salvo por cima. Ele não vai entender a codificação de texto porque não há uma, poderá interpretar errado os bytes e produzir caracteres espúrios que quando salvos causam a corrupção do arquivo original.

Você pode brincar num editor hexadecimal de mexer em alguns bytes que você sabe o que são, por exemplo pequenos textos misturados ao código, ou então editar um arquivo binário (por exemplo um que guarda seu *save state* de um jogo de computador) e mexer no número de pontos, poderes, etc.

Se você sabe que seu personagem tem 138 pontos de vida, você vai lá no hex editor e acha onde está o valor 8A (que é 138 em hexadecimal, dá pra ver isso na calculadora do Windows em modo programador) e altera para FF. Se alterou no lugar certo, seu personagem fica com 255 pontos de vida :D

Tem programas que ajudam a fazer isso.

Comment: eu acho que vou parar no hospício só de penssar em binarios. Obrigado entendi tudo.

Comment: Beleza, veja no [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) como marcar a resposta que lhe ajudou.

Comment: Tudo bem. Obrigado maniero e piovezan. Posso agradecer?

Comment: Pode mas o jeito certo é marcar a resposta que lhe atendeu mais. Essa é a forma que o site funciona. Pode marcar a do Maniero se quiser, a dele é bem completa, ele domina bastante informática e bem mais do que eu. :) A minha deve ter alguma coisa errada porque o pessoal nem deu votos positivos, mas se alguém comentar o que está errado eu procuro melhorar.

Comment: Ok  tudo bem vou fazer isto

Comment: Faça o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)!